# Tracking / Tracing feature in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh, cassandra-3.0

I understand that tracing on; feature is available in **cqlsh**,

I am trying to understand the Gossiping protocol and to read SS Tables,

1) Is there a way to track the Gossiping protocol? (NOTE : I could not see any information about that in Logs)
2) How to read the SS Tables? In which location SS Tables will be available in data folder?
3) I have a cluster, Is there a way to track the Write and Read operations happening withing the Cluster?
4) How to get the 'data structure' in the cqlsh in Cassandra?

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: 1. check the first movie on this link, between 09:30 and 13:45 minutes. It gives a good overview of what happens. Also check nodetool gossipinfo and, eventually, the Gossip class in Cassandra source code. https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/deep-into-cassandra-internals. 2. Here is a good explanation on SSTables https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataWritten.html. 3. What do you mean by that? Please, rephrase or give an example. 4. What do you mean by data structure?

Comment: @Horia, How to get the 'data structure' in the cqlsh in Cassandra? -> I know the underlying data storage is sorted hashmap in Cassandra, Is there a way to see the data structure of it in cqlsh? Or any other tool? I need a better understanding of underlying data structure of Cassandra. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: @Horia, How the co-ordinator node is choosen by Cassandra, How the replication nodes are choosen by Cassandra?

Comment: About the coordinator: when a client is issuing a request to a cluster, that request can go to any node, since all nodes are peers. The node that the client connected to becomes the coordinator node. The job of the coordinator is to act as a proxy between the client application and the nodes (or replicas) that own the data being requested. The coordinator determines which nodes in the ring should get the request based on the cluster configured partitioner and replica placement strategy.

Comment: About replication nodes: to keep it simple, the replicas are chosen based on the replication strategy. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeReplication_c.html For the complex answer, data distribution across the cluster depends on some factors: virtual nodes, replication strategy, partitioner and snitch. Please read this https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeAbout_c.html

Comment: About data storage: in Cassandra 3.0 there has been a refactoring of the storage engine. Here is the JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8099 and here are some more explanations https://github.com/pcmanus/cassandra/blob/8099_engine_refactor/guide_8099.md. Also, there are some discussions for a pluggable storage engine https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/77d289ea111680d1da39dc570faaaa634502ea56b74fa1836f88a466@%3Cdev.cassandra.apache.org%3E

Comment: I hope that my comments clarified some of your concerns. Please let me know so I can wrap it up in an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Horia, Can you comprise the answer by your words for each question, I already read through all the articles mentioned, I need to deep dive, so If u could explain the points I will ask my clarification.